# RXJS - dinstinctUntilChange with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

I want to fire `.subscribe()` for my oberservable if one of three object keys have changed.

it works, if I copy & paste the method for each key:

```
this.myService.loadData(this.dataContainer.id, true)
      .distinctUntilChanged((updatedData) => { return updatedData.relations; })
      .subscribe(updatedData => {
        console.log("relations changed",updatedData);
    });

this.myService.loadData(this.dataContainer.id, true)
      .distinctUntilChanged((updatedData) => { return updatedData.parent; })
      .subscribe(updatedData => {
        console.log("parent changed",updatedData);
    });

this.myService.loadData(this.dataContainer.id, true)
      .distinctUntilChanged((updatedData) => { return updatedData.children; })
      .subscribe(updatedData => {
        console.log("children changed",updatedData);
    });
```

if I set the `distinctUntilChanged` comparer to return the whole `updatedData` object, my subscribe never fires.

How can I combine the three `dinstinctUntilChanged` into one reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
const data$ = this.myService.loadData(this.dataContainer.id, true);

Observable
  .combineLatest(
    $data.distinctUntilChanged(data => updatedData.relations),
    $data.distinctUntilChanged(data => updatedData.parent),
    $data.distinctUntilChanged(data => updatedData.children),
    data => data
  )
  .subscribe(updatedData => {
    console.log("relation|parent|children changed", updatedData);
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

I ended up doing:

```
.distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a.key1 === b.key1 && a.key2 === b.key2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to return all of the data in the selector, and in the comparison function, compare the different properties:

```
this.myService.loadData(this.dataContainer.id, true)
  .distinctUntilChanged((updatedData) => { return updatedData; }, (a, b) => {
    return a.relations === b.relations && a.parent === b.parent && a.children === b.children;
  })
  .subscribe(updatedData => {
    console.log("updatedData", updatedData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach with a bit from lodash: (`pick` + `isEqual`)

```
  dashboardMessages$ = this.user$.pipe(
    map((user: User) => pick(user, 'subscriptionStatus', 'payoutsEnabled')),
    distinctUntilChanged(isEqual),
    map((user: Pick<User, 'subscriptionStatus' | 'payoutsEnabled'>) => {
      // there you go... with your partial user model
    }),

  );
```